# How to create an empty JQuery element and populate it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I need to create an empty JQuery element to be the outer scope list of a loop, for example :

```
const forms_data = ['Name', 'Email'];

const form = $();
for (const input_name of forms_data){
  form.insertAfter(`<input placeholder="${input_name}" / >`)
  form.append(`<input placeholder="${input_name}" / >`)
  form.after(`<input placeholder="${input_name}" / >`)
}

$('form').append(form);
```

But none of the ways of inserting new elements into it worked for me, according to other answers here, $() seems to be the correct way.

I don't want an outer div, I want all the inserted element to be siblings.

What am I doing wrong?

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lusfektu/16/

Comment: It's not necessary to use $() for this.  You could push all the elements to a `[]` and give that to append at the end.  I am slightly interested though in why you are using the different methods inside the for loop.

Comment: @Taplar just the different tries, none of them worked

Comment: @Taplar your list solution seem to perfectly fit my context, can you show how its done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is create the inputs and append them to the form, you can use a simple array, or map the elements.  `$.map` can be used to loop over an array, create new elements, and return them as a list at the end.  Using this we can create the array, and then append them all at once to the form.

```js
const forms_data = ['Name', 'Email'];

$('form').append($.map(forms_data, function(element){
  return `<input placeholder="${element}" / >`;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form></form>
```

Comment: Although I haven't used map, this fitted my context the best

Comment: map is a short cut vs you having to create the array and then push to it.  It removes that boiler plating.

Answer (score 4):

You should create form element like this `$('<form>)` and then you can use `append` method.

```js
const forms_data = ['Name', 'Email'];
const form = $('<form>');

forms_data.forEach(name => {
  form.append($('<input>', {placeholder: name}))
})

$('body').append(form);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Update: You could use `reduce` to make array of inputs or jquery objects and then append that array to form element at once.

```js
const forms_data = ['Name', 'Email'];

const inputs = forms_data.reduce((r, name) => {
  r.push($('<input>', {placeholder: name}))
  return r;
}, [])

$('form').append(inputs)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action=""></form>
```

Comment: I understand, but in my context the form element is already static on the page and I'm appending to it, so there's no outer div that should be created.

Comment: @Mojimi If you have `form` element in HTML then just select it and append inputs to it like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lusfektu/15/

Comment: @NenadVracar but then they would be rendered one by one, I would want them to be displayed all at once

Comment: This example is creating a detached form element, `$('<form>')`.  It will not be visible on the page until it is appended.  Using this detached form, it's adding all the elements to it, and then putting the form on the page.  So they *would* all show up at one time as you are asking for.

Comment: @Taplar actually I though he was selecting the form element already on page

Comment: Nope, the detached form lets you modify it however you want before it is put on the page.  This can reduce the number of times the browser redraws and increases performance.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to use `$()`, but those APIs won't work. Instead use `.add()`:

```
form = form.add($(`<input placeholder="${input_name}" / >`));
```

As the other answer notes, if you initialize the element to a `<form>` element then you *can* use the other APIs, but if you've already got a `<form>` on the page then that will be problematic. You could in that case initialize the container to something harmless like a `<div>` or a `<span>`.

Comment: Add returns a new object

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

`const form = $('<form>');`

Then simply use `append` on it like you did on the second line of your sample.